# VNC server for Android

Tags: android, chat, remote-access

I would like to use my rooted Android phone from my PC.

I have been testing several VNC server apps and none of them lets you control the Android device remotely.

I have tried Droid VNC and it no longer works in Android version 7.
If you just want to see the screen but don't care about controlling you can use TeamViewer QuickSupport.

What apps work like this?

I am looking for something under $20.  I have a Mac/Windows/Linux computer.  I don't mind controlling it from any of those.

Comment: By "text" you mean what? SMS? Then please see [here](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/remotedroid_controldroid#group_670) for examples. Anything else? Then please [edit] your question with specific details :)

Comment: @Izzy I'm believe the list you have linked mixes up devices that control Android remotely and devices that control your PC from Andriod.  For example XServer XSDL I believe controls X Server from your phone but it is under the Other apps to remote control your Android device.

Comment: Not really that mixed up. Thanks for the pointer, I've moved that app to a different category. But it's not really vice-versa, it rather doesn't really fit in any existing category: it is an XServer, allright. But on its own, it cannot control in either direction ;) </OT> I've pointed you to the first group on that page and asked you to clarify – you've pointed to the last group and asked me to clarify. Now, to enable people to answer your question, could you please clarify? ;)

Comment: @Izzy The question has been edited slightly to just ask about VNC servers for Android.  I had mentioned it in the original question but it is different.  I'm hopeful the 2 apps I have listed should clarify  Droid VNC and Alpha VNC.  I believe a VNC Server might be more useful because it appears with Accessibility options it might be possible without root but I can't seem to get Alpha VNC to work.  If you prefer I can edit the question to be slighly more inline with the original question if you would like.

Comment: William, what's your goal: A VNC server – or the ability of "texting as if came from my Rooted Phone"? Because in the latter case, asking for a VNC server is kind of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/66377/192154), as it's not the only solution. You find apps for both behind the link. If it's just for "texting", and by that you mean "SMS", apps specialized on that might be a better fit. Not having tried either of the two, I'm off with this comment; good luck for your hunt!

Comment: What are your price requirements? What OS do you want to control from? (Linux/Mac/Windows/etc?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have been using something called [Alpha VNC Lite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.abr.android.avnc).  Alpha VNC lite doesn't seem to work on the home screen but most other apps seem to work fine.  The device doesn't need to be rooted but you do not to enable a special keyboard and accessibility options.  It requires Android 5.0 and up.  You can use it for free.  VNC software never really works perfectly but it is still cool.

[image]

Comment: Please write one answer per product, and include: Price, screenshot of the client, features, and your personal comments about ease-of-use and responsiveness. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There also is [droidVNC-NG](https://github.com/bk138/droidVNC-NG) (which I authored). It does not require root and runs on Android 7+. It's open-source and available for free on Google Play and F-Droid.